# Handle the dependencies of a Maven Project after the build

Tags: java, maven, build, jar

So my question concerns the dependencies which are used in a Maven project. A small project with just one pom I could build using the `maven-shade-plugin`. So it contains all the dependencies I used with it and also can be build as an executable JAR. But what happens with bigger project with structures like:

```
+- myProject 
   +- pom.xml  ... <packaging>pom, aggregator (<modules>) of frontend & backend
   |
   +- frontend
   |  +- pom.xml  ... <parent>myProject, <packaging>pom, aggregator (<modules>) of window & ***
   |  |  
   |  +- window
   |  |  +- pom.xml  ... <parent>frontend
   |  |
   |  +- ***
   |     +- pom.xml  ... <parent>frontend
   |
   +- backend
      +- pom.xml  ... <parent>myProject, <packaging>pom, aggregator (<modules>) of database & ***
      |
      +- database
      |  +- pom.xml  ... <parent>backend
      |
      +- ***
         +- pom.xml  ... <parent>backend
```

Where `window` and `database` are just example projects in `frontend` and `backend` which could contain many more projects.

When I build something like this, I could also use the `shade` approach, but I have issues with that. Wouldn't that mean that when in the parent `myProject` are some dependencies set (with dependencyManagement) which get used by many different projects inside `frontend` and or `backend` for example, that every one of those projects when build to a JAR contains those dependencies respectively(JUnit for instance , and all contain it themselves)? And when some projects depend on each other for example `window` depends on `database` , that because `databse` is a dependecy it gets build into the JAR of `window` which then both seperately would contain the their own dependecies(both have JUnit jar) although they could use the same reference instead of having their own? Am I confusing something or would that be a bad idea to build it this way?

Is there a preferred or "better" way to approach the build of something like this?

Comment: Usually JUnit's JARs/dependencies are needed for unit tests at build time only, not for live runtime. Hence they aren't in any Fat JAR and for that declared with `<scope>test` in the POM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First this approach is called a multi module build which is a perfect fit for such things.

> Wouldn't that mean that when in the parent myProject are some dependencies set (with dependencyManagement) which get used by many different projects inside frontend and or backend for example,

There is a misunderstanding of what `dependencyManagement` means. Defining an artifact in `dependencyManagement` means that you can define a `dependency` without giving the version number in one of your modules (window, database).

The intention of `dependencyManagement` is to "manage" the list of used dependencies in a central location (usually the root of your multi module build (`myProject`).

So let us begin with an example. You define an artifact like the following in your dependencyManagement:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apiguardian</groupId>
      <artifactId>apiguardian-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Now you would like use this artifact (in other words the classes within the jar file). This will not add a dependency to your project. To none of them.

So now to really use it you have to define a `dependency` in one of your `pom.xml` file. For example `window` that would look like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apiguardian</groupId>
    <artifactId>apiguardian-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This will do the real trick. This means during the building of your module `window` this dependency (the jar file) will be available on the class path and you can compile your classes which use classes of that dependency. You can now add this dependency to several of your modules (keep in mind without defining the version).

After a time of development you want to upgrade the version of this artifact. This can easily being achieved by simply changing the version in the `dependencyManagement` location (only one location) and over all modules that version will be used.

So second misunderstanding. A jar which is build by Maven (as well by others) does **NOT** contain it's dependencies.

A jar which contains dependencies is called a `fat-jar`, `shaded-jar` or `jar-with-dependencies` or `executable-jar` (little bit different) which is usually not being created and should never being used as a dependencies to be consumed by others.

> And when some projects depend on each other for example window depends on database , that because databse is a dependecy it gets build into the JAR of window which then both seperately would contain the their own

As explained before a jar does not contain dependencies by default (and never should).

If you make a dependency between modules of your multi module build that's ok and the result is technically that the dependencies are found on the classpath during build and/or testing.

So another thing is about testing dependencies as you already mentioned. I use assertj library as an example. The artifact itself will be defined as you might already guessed in the `dependencyManagement` as described before. This means we add this artifact to the dependencyManagement.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apiguardian</groupId>
      <artifactId>apiguardian-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

So now you would like to use the `assertj` parts in one of your modules but only for testing. We enhance the `dependency` Part of the module ... because we have to write some tests which looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apiguardian</groupId>
    <artifactId>apiguardian-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So the most important thing you will see here is the `<scope>test</scope>`. This means the dependency is only "visible" during the unit tests. That means by default for test code which lives in `src/test/java`. So in each module you have to use assertj you have to add this dependency (with scope test).

So finally you would like to build an executable jar of your frontend and of your backend.

The usual way is to create a separate module `frontend-app` and `backend-app` which produces an executable jar file. The first thing you have to define the used modules in your `frontend-app`. This would look like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>window</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>supplemental modules for frontend</artifactId>
  </dependency>
   ...
</dependencies>
```

It's very important to see that the version given is done by placeholders `${project.version}` which is replaced automatically with the defined version of the project. The usage of `${project.version}` is an indicator that the dependency is build by your own multi module build.

Those dependencies are absolutely necessary to have a correct build order of your modules. By using the dependencies Maven can automatically determine the correct build order.

And of course you have to do the configuration to create the executable jar. This can be done via maven-shade-plugin or maybe maven-assembly-plugin (based on the use case). If this a kind of Spring Boot project you should use the spring-boot-maven-plugin for that purpose.

If you need to write some integration tests in this module you have to add the appropriate dependencies for that as well.

The usual modules will not produce a shaded/fat jar by default. There is usually no reason to do so.

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: thank you very much! Your answer cleared some things up for me. But as it seems to always be with me, I missphrase my questions. I understood beforehand what dependencyManagement meant, it just got tangled up in my blabber. And I used fat-Jar on purpose because, even if bad, it's the only answer I know aon. What I really want to know is, how to build such a project so I have a executable jar or a bat or exe or whatever to start the program and have everything packaged with it(in a surrounding file system), so I can copy(or even install) the program to another pc and still use it.

Comment: And I thought and still think that I have to get all the dependencies I need for the program inside the "package", because  it would just have a reference to them, which doesn't exist on another machine. And probably this is the more severe missconception, this probably the easiest part and maybe it does even happen auromatically with Maven and I just did it wrong, because I never had this outcome. Probably I am just stupid with this and will be feeling really dumb once I know, but as it is sometimes the easiest concepts just fly over my head. But thank you this far anyway^^

Comment: The description gave the impression that the difference between dependencyManagement and dependencies is not clear. An executable jar can be created via maven-shade-plugin,maven-assembly-plugin or in case of Spring boot via spring-boot-maven-plugin (or for quarkus etc. something alike). Also I have described where such module should be located. An exe for Windows can not be produced with Java in general..Creating an installation package usually can be built with maven-assembly-plugin. If a kind of installer there things like install4j...

Comment: All dependencies needed will be packaged into an so called executable jar (via maven-shade-plugin) or with maven-assembly-plugin...

Comment: Ah, Thank you! Now I have a idea. I read a little bit into the assembly-plugin and you're right, it does exactly what I want. I just have to figure out how to configure it right, but firstly I have to get my project going, then I can figure that out as I go. Thank you very much, you were a great help!^^ Have a nice day.